# Redirecionamento automático

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso de algo para ficar escutando a url ou seja se a url:

http://localhost:15000/api/ReturnPayment/retornoPayPal

for acessa quero redirecionar para outra url. O problema é que a url e gerada dinamicamente assim

```
http://localhost:15000/api/ReturnPayment/retornoPayPal?id=" + params.orderNo
```

Queria saber se tem algum jeito de redirecionar para outra url somente a partir da url padrão, ou seja `http://localhost:15000/api/ReturnPayment/retornoPayPal/` ignorando tudo o que vem depois

Já tenho alguns meios de redirecionamento, só que são fixos

```
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/api/ReturnPayment/retorno', '/');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/api/ReturnPayment/retornoPayPal', '/');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Não consigo passar como parâmetro somente uma parte da url para isto funcionar tenho que passar a url exata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se existe os parâmetros com `GET`.

**PHP**

```
<?php 
 if(!isset($_GET)) header('Location: suapagina.php');
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
var pageURL = window.location.href.split('&');

if(pageURL.length <= 1) window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Estou trabalhando com JavaScript, como posso fazer isso usando JavaScript ?

Comment: Pelo localhost associei com php, mas pode sim já edito

Comment: Estava usando localhost para teste. funcionou deste jeito somente troquei o split por um replace para funcionar no meu caso, muito obrigado.